# Why require a smallest set in a recursive definition of natural numbers?

Tags: math, computer-science

From the Wikipedia entry on [recursive definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition):

> An inductive definition of a set describes the elements in a set in terms of other elements in the set. For example, one definition of the set N of natural numbers is:
>
> 1. 1 is in N.
> 2. If an element n is in N then n+1 is in N.
> 3. N is the smallest set satisfying (1) and (2).
>
> There are many sets that satisfy (1) and (2) - for example, the set {1, 1.649, 2, 2.649, 3, 3.649, ...} satisfies the definition.

I don't understand why (3) is needed. In the example given, it states that 1.649 is a member of this set but 1.649 doesn't satisfy (1) or (2).

Why is (3) needed and how is 1.649 in the set?

Comment: I didn't realize this was such a bad question and that recursive definitions aren't related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule 2 on the list is an "if", not an "if and only if". They're not rules for generating the set, they're rules for deciding if a set is allowed. The set {1, 1.649, 2, 2.649, 3, 3.649, ...} satisfies rule 1, because 1 is in the set. It satisfies rule 2, because for every element of the set, that element plus one is also in the set. In fact, even the set of real numbers satisfies the first two rules, and it has uncountably many "extra" elements that you don't need.

Only rule 3 stops you adding arbitrary extra elements to the set, by saying the set has to be the smallest possible one.

Answer (score 2):

The first two requirements do not ascertain anything about certain elements not being in the set. While we are guaranteed to have 1, there is no reason for the set not to contain 1.649.

And clearly we want the set of natural numbers to be unique and just {0, 1, ...}, since we need to be able to make assertions about all of them.

To exemplify, One basic statement we want to be able to make is that any natural number is either a successor of a natural number or 1. It doesn't help to have an equivalent chain starting at another number in the set for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
(1) 1 is a natural number`
(2) If N is a natural number, than N+1 is a natural number as well
```

This is an *implication*, not an *equivalence*. What this says is - if for any number these conditions hold, it is a natural number. It says nothing about whether there are other natural numbers.

```
(3) N is the smallest set satisfying (1) and (2)
```

This says precisely that the first two conditions are exhausting. Not only every number that satisfies them is natural, but also - any number that does not, is not natural.

The condition (3) could also be rephrased as

`Every natural number can be obtained by a finite number of applications of (2) on (1)`

or simply

`Nothing else is a natural number`